# Cannot resolve 'R.string.gcm_send_message'

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Any idea why am I getting this error? Together with `cannot resolve R.string.token_error_message` and `cannot resolve R.string.registrationProgressBar` when trying to use `GCM`?

I was thinking the issue was in the `Manifest` so I did various changes, but nothing helped.

Manifest:

```
<manifest
    package="com.example.android.bluetoothchat"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- GCM START -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothchat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothchat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- GCM END -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- GCM START -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothchat" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- GCM END -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: mind the imports, you might have imported your local project R, which masks the R of the gcm

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: It actually might be the reason. But I can't find an import of the R. Do you know what is the right R import for the GCM?

Comment: @mohax I am using an Android Studio.

Comment: Are you using lastes versions of libs? You can check it in gradle file and in SDK manager

Comment: I am using google play services revision 27 (info gotten from the SDK manager) and then I have this in my gradle: `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3` and then this: `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0"`

Comment: I think you may need to add `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0` as well to your dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [link](http://rmarcejaeger.com/2015/09/18/tutorial-how-to-implement-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-part-1-client-app/). It seems to be, that you should create your own strings in yours projects `strings.xml`and add also a `ProgressBar` to yours layout

Strings to add (from link abowe):

```
<string name="gcm_send_message">Token retrieved and sent to server! You can now use gcmsender to
    send downstream messages to this app.</string>
<string name="registering_message">Generating InstanceID token...</string>
<string name="token_error_message">An error occurred while either fetching the InstanceID token,
    sending the fetched token to the server or subscribing to the PubSub topic. Please try
    running the sample again.</string>
```

Also yours layout must contain `ProgressBar` with id `registrationProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/registrationProgressBar" />
```